# Library plugin :: Library resources not found

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm currently converting an Android Library to a Unity plugin.
I got a long way already, but now I'm stuck on the point where the resources of the Library cannot be accessed from Unity.

The application is running fine, until I actually call a view from the library. 
Here's the error log I'm getting at that moment:

```
12-12 13:37:36.495: W/ResourceType(32155): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1 is beyond type entryCount 1
12-12 13:37:36.495: W/ResourceType(32155): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030001 (t=2 e=1) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
12-12 13:37:36.500: D/AndroidRuntime(32155): Shutting down VM
12-12 13:37:36.500: W/dalvikvm(32155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4109a2a0)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.j ava:1026)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParse r(Resources.java:2131)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources. java:865)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater .java:394)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater .java:352)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.mycompany.mylibrary.components.AndroidWebViewD ialog.<init>(AndroidWebViewDialog.java:140)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.mycompany.mylibrary.FunctionAndroidLibrary.Sho wDialog(FunctionAndroidLibrary.java:163)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.mycompany.mylibrary.FunctionAndroidLibrary.but tonREGISTER(FunctionAndroidLibrary.java:94)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.mycompany.myUnityProjectAndroidLibraryTest$1.r un(AndroidLibraryTest.java:78)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615 )
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92 )
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav a:4898)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit .java:773)
12-12 13:37:36.505: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- These resources are physically present in the library `.jar` file.
- `setContentView()` is disabled from the Unity Android project

Anyone who can help out?
Thank you in advance!

**[EDIT]**
I think I found the problem here:
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

```
Important change: We have changed the way Library Projects generate and package R classes:
The R class is not packaged in the jar output of Library Projects anymore.
Library Project do not generate the R class for Library Projects they depend on. Only main application projects generates the Library R classes alongside their own.
```

Does anyone know what is the best solution to solve this in combination with Unity3D?

Comment: I was going to say that I don't think you can include IDs in a jar. Android Library projects can have their own IDs, but they are not compiled separately, they are compiled together with the IDs from the host project. I build an SDK for developers, and I've yet to find a way to deliver it as a jar and still use resource IDs.

Comment: Did you ever do this for Unity3D specifically?
I don't mind passing along the source code of the SDK/library, but Unity simply won't recognize the R file of the referenced project...

Comment: Sorry, I have not, I just thought I might be able to help in a general way. The crux is that if Unity treats the Library Project as a separate jar from the main project, then IDs defined in that jar won't be available to the main project, because the whole project uses only the IDs defined in the main project.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's caused by an inproper post packaging process of Unity3D.**It generate the dex file before aapt generate R class which contains resource id**.So there is no chance for you to rely on static resource id.

I have solved this problem by writing an editor plugin for Unity3D.But I cannot release it now since it's buggy and I'm too busy to fix it at the moment.

But due to your problem is porting the code.I suggest you change your resource loading code in java to adopt this problem caused by Unity3D.

```
// context should be the activity of your unity3d application which raise the call to your plugin.

// Loading string
String myResString = context.getResources().getString(
        context.getResources().getIdentifier("sample_string",
                                             "string",
                                             context.getPackageName()));

// Loading image
AlertDialog.Builder tDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
tDialog.setIcon(
      context.getResources().getIdentifier("sample_icon", "drawable", context.getPackageName())
);
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, with no luck. It always gets 0 as the resource id. :(

Answer (score 1):

See the following post:

[Custom Resources in a Unity Android Project](http://www.twodee.org/blog/?p=4951)

which shows what the problem is and how you can retrieve the resource id.

Comment: You will generally receive more favorable response if you include the relevant information from the link within the answer on SO, instead of just saying "Read this".  You want your answer to remain useful even if the blog post you link to goes away.

Comment: You're right. Writing the answer with iPad on my bed leaded that short answer. Sorry again for the short comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues but found a clean way to do this on Unity 4.3.

I was integrating Google Play Game Services library with my own Java code and making a plugin from all this.

Firstly make sure the library project is marked as a library for your Android project.
When you export the jar from eclipse, export the res folder of your derived project, and not the library project. The resources from library project are automatically merged in your derived project. After this step you should have a jar containing class files and a res folder.

Extract this res folder from the jar and place it in your Plugins/Android folder.

Now when you build your project from Unity, it should all work.

EDIT: I think you can just copy the res folder of the derived project directly into Unity's Plugins/Android folder. No need to export into the jar.

Answer (score -1):

I copy xml-file to Android/Plugin/res/xml/ and this resource found!!! But When I copy laoyout-file to Android/Plugin/res/layout - I receive exception, when build unity3d for android:

error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
/Android-SDK/sdk/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Android-SDK/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.prime31.IAB:com.facebook.android:com.google.android.gms -S "/Projects/bottle_client_unity/Bottle_Unity/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook/res" -S "/Projects/bottle_client_unity/Bottle_Unity/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res"

stderr[
res/drawable/com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
res/drawable-ldpi/com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
res/drawable-hdpi/com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
res/drawable-xhdpi/com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited